# Bean not using test resources during tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application, where I extended the /monitoring/info endpoint by extending the InfoContributor:

```
@Component
public class MyInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {

    @Value("${filename}")
    private String filename;

    @Override
    public void contribute(Builder builder) {
        ...
    }

}
```

The contributor reads a file which name is the value of the "filename" variable and populates the response with it's content.

Then I implemented a test for it where I replaced the usual property value with the one that is specific for this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "filename=/test/some-file"
})
public class MyInfoContributorTest {
    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnBuildInfo() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/monitoring/info"))
                .andExpect(content().string("..."))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

The test works, but with an issue: It's looking for this "/test/some-file" file (which is specified in the TestPropertySource) in the main/resources instead of test/resources. 
I also tried the approach with using a test profile, the result is the same.

Is it possible to make this component look for files in the test resources?

Comment: Should that not be classpath:some-file?

Comment: Why? The property holds the name of the file, and it's found and read correctly if I specify an existing file in that annotation. The problem is that it's looking for it in the main resources, and I need it to look for it in test resources

Comment: did you try defining both `properties` and `locations` in the `@TestPropertySource` ?

Comment: @diginoise replied to your answer

Comment: Why wouldn't it look in the `src/main/resources`? I assume you are actually loading this file at runtime.

Just because the test property source is changing does not mean it is expecting the location of the resource is kept in to change to a test resource.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I said in the question that even during tests the contributor is trying to read the file from main/resources, the question is how to make it read test/resources

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@TestPropertySource(
    locations  = "classpath:test.properties",
    properties = {"filename=/test/some-file"} )
```

for `test.properties` placed in `src/test/resources`.

Please also mind that locations can be a String array and order of entries defines the precedence and `properties` have the highest precedence overriding properties defined in files found in `locations`.

Comment: how does it solve the problem that it looks for the "/test/some-file" file in main/resources, not in test/resources? It's not about the property, it's about where the file itself is looked for.

Comment: @GreenFireman Spring will *NOT* look for `/test/some-file` as this is only a property value for a property named `filename`. Spring however will look for property file `test.properties` located in `src/test/resources`.

Comment: The point is that in the contributor I'm reading the file which filename is specified in the property, and even during tests it's trying to read it from main/resources instead of test/resources. The file, not the property!